# defines and logic in c, microprocessors

Tags: c, macros

What is wrong with this code? I am new to c but I cannot understand what I have done wrong by using macros inside if statements. It gives me an unexpected token error.

```
#define PBrun PORTBbits.RB10
#define pressed 0;
#define released 1;

int debouncedone = true;

void debouncetimerdone(){
    debouncedone = true;
    if (PBrun == pressed){
        debouncedone = false;
    }
}
```

When I replace the macros with their meaning the code works fine.

Comment: Is there any reason for you to use `#define`s instead of constants?

Comment: @void_ptr: C does not allow to define true constants. `cont` qualified objects are still variables. `#define` is the correct way. Even leaving apart that the first line could not be defined by a constant anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the semi-colons at the end of the macro definitions:

i.e.
Change from

```
#define pressed 0;
#define released 1;
```

to

```
#define pressed 0
#define released 1
```

With the semi-colon, the `if` statement would look like this after the macro substitution:

```
 if (PBrun == 0;){
        debouncedone = false;
    }
```

This obviously produces syntax errors.

Comment: You can [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you :)